# error in wordpress form

Tags: php, wordpress, forms

I am writing my code here. My form is not sending submission data. 
When submitting data I am getting this error :

> "Failed to send your message. Please try later or contact the
>   administrator by another method"

Also when taking form code in admin panel, I can also see another error :

> "Unavailable names (name) are used for form controls"

```
<p class="name"><label for="name">Name (required)</label>[text* name] </p>
    <p class="email"><label for="email">Email (required)</label>[email* email] </p>
    <p class="phone"><label for="phone-contact">Phone Contact</label>[text phone-contact] </p>
    <p class="date"><label for="date">Date</label>[text date] </p>
    <p class="select-course">[select menu "Select Course" "Course 1" "Course 2" "Course 3"]</p>
    <p>[submit "Application"]</p>
```

If anybody knows please help me.

Comment: are you using any wordpress plugin here? perhaps you are using wordpress contact form 7 plugin. maybe you need to change the first form field 'name' to something else like username or contactname

Comment: Sir,why getting Failed to send your message. Please try later or contact the administrator by another method"  error when submitting?

Answer (score 0):

you can resolve the admin error by change the "`[text* name]`" to "`[text* user-name]`"
This error is coming because you can use "name" as input name in cntact form 7

the second error is coming because your server is not configured to send the mail. or if you are on local server the server is bydefault not configured to send the mail.

or

if you have a live website. please ask to your server adminitrator to configure to smtp on your server.

or

if you have  third party smtp detais,  you can configire it in setting->writting
in this section you can set your credentials to send the mail.

Comment: can do it from wp-admin?

Comment: am new to wordpress, i didnt see mail config settings there,where i can see?

Comment: test mail failed in smtp,you know why?

Comment: yoursite.com/wp-admin/options-writing.php  hot this url after login into wp-admin. you will see "Post via email" section put your smtp details here and test your contact form 7.